# "on par with" vs "on a par with"

Tags: grammar, idioms

Which of "on par with" and "on a par with" is the more correct way of saying that two things are of equal value, and why?

Examples from a couple of google searches:

- "His verbal intelligence was not *on a par* with his maths"
- "Arctic sea ice melting *on par with* 2007 record"

Comment: I think it's is General Reference that #2 is "newspaper headline style", which commonly omits articles in this way.

Comment: (to save valuable space in headlines)

Comment: +1 Leave open. The question is about "on par" versus "on *a* par" generally, not just about the examples. This is not a general reference question just on the observation that one sample text turns out to be in headline style. (It's not a general reference question *anyway*, because general reference does not mean "common knowledge", it means "there's an entry in a reputable online reference work that directly answers this question".)

Comment: Those who thought this was GR may try and answer it now.

Comment: @MετάEd: You've only captured half of the definition there, the other half being "this question is too basic." If _general reference_ simply meant "an entry in a reputable online reference work that directly answers this question", then I think a LOT more questions could be closed. For example, single word requests can be found in a dictionary, but no one wants to start at _aardvark_ and keep reading until the right word is found. I think GR implies "too basic" first, with the "single reference" part being a confirmation of that overly fundamental nature. Just my interpretation.

Comment: I wanted to interpret it that way too but was disabused of that notion by SE staff. GR means only "you should have looked it up".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should favour "on a par with", because it's the more commonly used expression, and has been around as such for a long time (longer than the game of golf, on which more in a moment).

It can be abbreviated to "on par with" for headline-style abbreviations. You should only do that in headlines.

In golf, it is normal to talk both of a player being "on par" meaning that they took the number of strokes that is the standard measure for the course in question, and also that they are "on par with" another player, meaning that they are currently (or finished) with an equal number of strokes. Because of this you will sometimes find "on par with" used figuratively for other contexts even outside of headline style and golf.

But since that remains a less common use, I'd still advise you to favour "on a par with" in your own writing.

Ngrams don't mean everything, but this chart suggests a strong preference for "on a par with" for both British and American use.

[image]

The Corpus of Contemporary American English finds 370 uses of "on a par with" to 348 of "on par with", or 322 to 272 if we exclude spoken news, sports magazines, and sports newspapers to reduce those using the term as golf jargon. Less strong a preference as found in ngrams, but still suggesting "on a par with" is the more common form.

Comment: [Just as a note, extending the timeline out to 2008 (I think that's as recent as you can get on Google ngrams) usage of *on a par with* seems to be declining while *on par with* seems to be increasing.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+par+with%3Aeng_us_2012%2Con+a+par+with%3Aeng_us_2012%2Con+par+with%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Con+a+par+with%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: @Jim it does even before that, but it's got some way to go.

Comment: I think it's worth noting here that the declining usage of *on a par with* that @Jim mentioned is very much american-led. As of 2008 the usage ratio according to ngrams is ~2:1 for en_us and ~9:1 for en_gb.

Comment: As of the [2019 ngram corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+par+with%3Aeng_us_2019%2Con+a+par+with%3Aeng_us_2019%2Con+par+with%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Con+a+par+with%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), usage in the U.S. crossed over, with "on par with" being more common.

Answer (score 4):

If you are writing for someone in the States, "on par with" is the best choice. The phrase "on a par with" is seldom used. But it looks like it is used more across the pond in the beautiful British Isles. However, if you are writing an academic piece, I'd avoid it altogether and use "at the same level".

Comment: I can find plenty of American uses, from James Madison arguing that the United States should ratify the Constitution, through to the present day. While Americans do seem to favour "on a par with" over "on par with" less than the British, they do still seem to favour it.

Comment: Also, Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary offers this definition of "par": "2 : common level : EQUALITY — usu. use with 'on' <judged the recording to be on a par with previous ones>." House style at the U.S. magazine where I work is to use "on a par with," not "on par with." As J.R. notes in another answer, confusion is likely due to the operation of such phrases as "up to par" and "under par."

Comment: That Merriam-Webster's definition should say "usu. used"—not "usu. use."

Answer (score 0):

NOAD lists four idiomatic usages of the word *par*:

[image]

My guess is, if the use of an article seems inappropriate, that's because you're confusing ***on a par with*** with ***above par*** or ***up to par***.

In short, this looks like a case where the inclusion (or exclusion) of an article depends on the choice of preposition. As for the usage in your question:

> Arctic sea ice melting on par with 2007 record

I agree with the comment made by FumbleFingers – that looks like a headline as opposed to a complete sentence.