# How to concisely say that pairs of items are on par with each other?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, comparisons

> 1. A1 and A2 are on par with each other.
> 2. B1 and B2 are on par with each other.

So

> 3. A's are on par with each other.
> 4. B's are on par with each other.

I want to say 3 and 4 in one single sentence without repeating "on par with each other". How can I do that?

Comment: A's are on par with one another, and so are B's. 'In a par' is not exactly familiar.

Comment: [Traditionally,](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/reciprocal-pronouns-each-other-and-one-another) *with each other* is used for two things, and *with one another* is used for more. But as the website I link to says, this distinction is disappearing. (Although to me, *with one another* still doesn't sound quite right for two things.)

Comment: @StuW: Being a pair is not the same as being on par.

Comment: Oops! How about *A1 and A2 are on par with each other - so are B1 and B2.* ?

Comment: Further to various suggestions for rephrasing, the idiom is "on a par with", not "on par with".

Comment: Please see the comment thread under my answer the related edit.  It seems I was mistaken.

Comment: @RosieF, see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103664/on-par-with-vs-on-a-par-with)

Comment: I was under the impression that "On par with" is specifically not exactly the same, it's a way to say that they are very similar in many areas.  If this is the case then I'd call each pair "roughly equivalent".  It looks from some of the answers that there may be a more exacting definition that I'm not considering.

Comment: @BillK Good question. What does "on par with" exactly mean? Does it mean "be equivalent to"?

Comment: A1⊕A2, B1⊕B2, where ⊕ = on par.

Comment: @MaskedMan-仮面の男 you see, you repeated "on par"!

Comment: @Sasan Not really, the purpose of defining the ⊕ operator is to prevent the repetition. It is not much different from adding a "respectively" at the end.

Comment: @MaskedMan-仮面の男 Since ⊕ = on par, and you mentioned ⊕ twice, then you in fact repeated "on par".

Comment: @Sasan I repeated ⊕ to avoid repeating "on par". You are not supposed to replace ⊕ back to "on par", that is the point.

Comment: ***'on par'*** in which sense? 'equally good'? 'equally priced'? 'about the same'? 'similar quality/ reliability'? You need to supply some context. 'par' is only generally used in golf, it's not the word you'd typical choose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would go with this, or some small variation of it:

> The As are on par with one another, as are the Bs.

Note that it's not *in a par*.  Either *on par* or *on a par* can be used.

Comment: This could also be _**A1 and A2** are on par with one another [or each other], as are **B1 and B2**_ if the OP really wanted to list the components.

Comment: I'm not saying the estimated prevalence from Google Books is completely accurate, but it claims 21,800 hits for [*they are **on a par** with*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22they+are+on+a+par+with%22), against only 1,520 for [*they are **on par** with*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22they+are+on+par+with%22). Personally, I'd have expected a more marked preference, but even at that level your assertion is clearly incorrect so far as actual usage is concerned (and I never heard of any pedants supporting your position on logical / syntactic grounds).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, interesting, thanks.  I've never heard the phrase "on a par" but apparently it's legit.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 15):

The other answer is a good one. Here's another suggestion:

> A1 and B1 are on par with A2 and B2, respectively.

However, this wouldn't work if you were talking about (A1,A2) and (B1,B2,B3).

---

> [Respectively](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/respectively)
>
> adverb
>
> 1. in precisely the order given; sequentially.
> 2. (of two or more things, with reference to two or more things previously mentioned) referring or applying to in a parallel or sequential way:
>      ***Joe and Bob escorted Betty and Alice, respectively.***

Comment: +1. My engineering masters had many instances of this, not matter how hard I tried to mix the writing up so as not to repeat myself I ended up reverting all the other clumsy attempts back to variations of 'respectively'.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen no reference by anyone answering, or commenting to ***parity***.

How about ***...and the B's have parity too***?

Comment: You missed my answer, below. _Both the A's and the B's are in parity._

Comment: @Vector Apologies. But I honestly didn't see your answer, and am quite mystified as to why mine has scored three positive votes, and yours a negative two - especially since you provided more information. Anyway +1 from me.

Comment: @DarrenRinger also used _parity_ in another answer, below. IMO it works much better than the answers here that are fumbling around to make _in par_ work. I added the information about usage of _parity_ later - I think it was down-voted before because it was too short not everyone understood how _parity_ can be used.

Answer (score 2):

This one is clear and indefinite regarding number.

> A's are on a par with other A's and B's with other B's.

You might get a little more readability substituting a comma for the "and".

> A's are on a par with other A's, B's with other B's.

Answer (score 2):

I might modify the phrase and verbiage ever-so-slightly, but possibly destroying the original phrase, to:

> Both A's and B's maintain parity within their respective categories.

Or less drastic, but possibly more ambiguous or straining the original phrase,

> Both A's and B's are on par within their respective categories.

Answer (score 1):

> A1 is on par with A2, and B1 with B2.
>
> A1 is on par with A2; B1, with B2.
>
> A1 is on par with A2, as is B1 with B2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how clear the meaning of this one is, but I think it would make sense to say

> The A's and B's are both on par with themselves.

Using "themselves" should indicate that the A's and B's are on par internally, and not with each other, but it's not the clearest solution.

Answer (score -1):

Both the A's and the B's are in parity.

> Parity can be used in this way, see
>   [***Parity:***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/parity?s=t)
>
> 1:equality, as in amount, status, or character. 2:equivalence;
>   correspondence; similarity; analogy.
>
> *British Dictionary definitions for parity:*
>
> 1:equality of rank, pay, etc 2:close or exact analogy or equivalence

Parity is a noun and is generally used to represent a state of equality/equivalence, etc. Thus, 'in parity' suggests that each group, the A's, and the B's, is in a state of parity with respect to itself - a state of equality or equilibrium (not the same), which appears to be what you want to express.