# Is *on par* colloquial?

Tags: vocabulary, colloquialisms, register

I need some more synonymous constructions for *equal, identical, the same* in context such as *Models A and B performed essentially equal on task X*. Is *on par* a valid replacement for *equal/ identical/ the same* here, or is *on par* only suited for informal contexts?

Comment: It's [on a par (with)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/on_a_par_with), and it certainly doesn't mean "equal, identical, the same"; it's far more approximate. The examples at that link seem neither particularly colloquial nor formal.

Comment: @AndrewLeach *equal* can also mean *approximately equal* depending on the context. In my context *equal* is an approximate *equal* and thus semantically synonymous to *on par*. The preposition *with* also can be dropped depending on the construction. *A performed on par with B* but *A and B performed on par* are both valid construction. Also: I put *essentially equal* in my example, to emphasis the approximate equality.

Comment: Depending on if use is adjectival or adverbial, "on par with" means "equivalent(ly) to" in the sense of "on or at the same level as."  I'm not sure what you're getting at with "colloquial," though. If you're asking if it's used in the vernacular, i.e., whether it's a common expression, then know that it is. If you're asking if you can use it in a formal setting, then the answer's iffy. While it literally means "equality in standing," it's not uncommon for people associating "par" with golf to perceive it as a sports metaphor, and sports metaphors are frowned upon as sexist in formal settings.

Comment: To be clear, "on par with" isn't a sports metaphor or even a metaphor at all.  That means that it technically qualifies for full acceptance in formal communication.  However, what is actually accepted in settings where formal communication is required, like professional settings, isn't based on technicalities but is based on perceptions.  If a phrase is perceived or just could predictably be perceived as being offensive, even if incorrectly, then it is to be avoided.  In formal communication, the standard isn't just the avoidance of evil but also the avoidance of the appearance of evil.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman What on earth does Golf/ sports have to do with sexism...?

Comment: Related (and perhaps quite relevant): ["on par with" vs "on a par with"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103664/on-par-with-vs-on-a-par-with). This question drew some responses suggesting that "on par with" may have been influenced by the English idiomatic expressions "under par" and "up to par".

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear out a common misconception beforehand: as opposed to many people's claims, "par" *does not* originate from golf. "Par" is a loanword from Latin that means "equal" and the word itself is used in most of the Latin languages (and also in Dutch as "paar") to signify 2 equal things, a pair.

For the "on par" expression: according to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/par) "on par" is a standard (not colloquial or technical) and is listed as a common expression in Business English, as well as the derived expression "subpar" meaning "below average" or "below expected standard".

Comment: ***on par with*** means more like "at the same level" or "in the same range as"  but not necessarily equal or identical.  This answer, as written, may be misleading.

Comment: @Jim That is why I put *essentially equal* in my example. Meaning *approximately equal*.

Comment: @lotolmencre - "essentially" does not mean "approximately" it means "in essence" which essentially means they can be treated as equal in some context for some purpose.

Comment: @Jim Yes, and in some contexts, such as mine, performing essentially equal is constituted by performing approximately equal. Thus the words are interchangeable in my context.

Comment: @Jim good point. The "equal" in the sentence refers to "loanword", so I'm saying that "par" in Latin means equal and that meaning carries into the Latin languages (and Dutch). I'm not talking about the "on par with" expression as a whole, just clearing out a common misconception (of "on par" meaning same level or range originating from golf) beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [an example](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20par%20with%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1998,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) from The United States Surgeon General's Report in 1999:

> It is a work of real significance, on par with the Surgeon General's historic first report on smoking and health published in 1964.

[And another](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20par%20with%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1934,cd_max:1990&lr=lang_en), from a [1975 publication on the Constitutional Protection of Equality](https://books.google.com/books?id=XbeazCBcp3EC&pg=PA86&dq=%22on+par+with%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwic-vzH57nkAhVGM6wKHct2CN0Q6AEwAnoECAIQAg):

> This was justified by the functional difference between the father and the mother of an illegitimate child in case of absence of a family; the mother is then responsible for personal care, which is on par with financial support, but the father can ...

In neither of these cases is it seen in a "colloquial" sense; rather, it's seen in a serious, not to say sobersided, publication.

Note, however, that it has only recently come to the fore—and not quite to the fore, really, since the synonymous phrase "commensurate with," though in decline, [still eclipses it by a wide margin](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+par+with%2Ccommensurate+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20par%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccommensurate%20with%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Con%20par%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccommensurate%20with%3B%2Cc0).

**Edit, thanks to Tim Lymington**:

As Tim correctly notes, "on a par with" [is much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+par+with%2Con+a+par+with%2Ccommensurate+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20par%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20a%20par%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccommensurate%20with%3B%2Cc0) than "on par with." It's essentially the same usage, though, and occurs in such non-colloquial works as [a translation of Aquinas's *Summa Theologicae*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20a%20par%20with%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

Comment: I have only heard the phrase as "on a par with": I suspect it's merely a matter of idiom.

Comment: @TimLymington: Yes, and thanks. I've added that to the answer.

Comment: on par with [noun] or on a par with [noun] just to be precise.